# Exclude component that breaks Angular Universal

Tags: angular, typescript, nodes

I used [ng-toolkit](https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit) with `ng add @ng-toolkit/universal` to add Angular Universal support to my project.

I am able to create the prod build with no errors plus I am able to run the server, again without any errors. It just get "stuck" when request comes to it (nodeJS does not render any output).

I found out, that one of my components is breaking server-side rendering. I found out that the issue is with the Mat-Carousel:

component:

```
export class BannerComponent {

  slides: any[] = [
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    { image: 'assets/banner/banner-one.png' },
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    { image: 'assets/banner/banner-two.png' },
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    { image: 'assets/banner/banner-three.png' }
  ];

}
```

template:

```
<section class="sec-space-b" id="banner">
    <mat-carousel
        timings="250ms ease-in"
        [autoplay]="true"
        interval="5000"
        color="accent"
        maxWidth="auto"
        proportion="25"
        slides="5"
        [loop]="true"
        [hideArrows]="false"
        [hideIndicators]="false"
        [useKeyboard]="true"
        [useMouseWheel]="false"
        orientation="ltr"
      >
        <mat-carousel-slide
            #matCarouselSlide
            *ngFor="let slide of slides; let i = index"
            overlayColor="#00000000"
            [image]="slide.image"
            [hideOverlay]="false"
        ></mat-carousel-slide>
    </mat-carousel>
</section>
```

How can I solve this problem? Can I somehow exclude particular component from the Server-Side build?

Comment: do you see any errors in the browser debug console.  can you also share the contents of the scripts ?  what does npm xxxx actually do

Comment: here you can find the whole the repo: https://github.com/immad-hamid/website-csn and the packages I have used. Well I have used ng-toolkit. No error at all, not even the browser's console the browser shows nothing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fix is simple, you should use a [PLATFORM_ID](https://angular.io/api/core/PLATFORM_ID) token together with the `isPlatformBrowser` or `isPlatformServer` method.

Inside your template use the `#ngIf` statement:

```
<section class="sec-space-b" id="banner" *ngIf="isBrowser">
```

And inside the component code initialize the `isBrowser` field as:

```
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-banner',
  templateUrl: './banner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./banner.component.scss']
})
export class BannerComponent implements OnInit {

  public isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);

  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any) { }
}
```

You can read more about `isPlatformServer` and `isPlatformBrowser` in this article (they are used there):
https://www.twilio.com/blog/create-search-engine-friendly-internationalized-web-apps-angular-universal-ngx-translate

You can also check out my talk about Angular Universal (13:26 - about running different code on browser and server):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J42mqpVsg0k

Comment: This works well. Note that the [angular-universal documentation](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/main/docs/gotchas.md#strategy-2-guards) actually warns against using `isPlatfomBroser`and `isPlatformServer` and recommends setting up shim components instead. You might however still want to use this as it is just easier. he shim components however generalize better.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that is to create a directive like the following:

```
import { isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';
import { Directive, Inject, OnInit, PLATFORM_ID, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[ssrExclude]' })
export class SSRExcludeDirective implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private readonly _viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
        private readonly _templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private readonly _platformId: Object
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        if (isPlatformServer(this._platformId)) {
            this._viewContainer.clear();
        } else {
            this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._templateRef);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
<section *ssrExclude>
    YOUR_HTML_CONTENT
</section>
```