# Client-side render some components when using Angular Universal

Tags: angular, seo, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, privacy

I am using Angular Universal for most of my website so that I can pre-render the content for SEO. It is meant to be a public facing site.

I would like to be able to make certain components client-side rendered ONLY to avoid bundling content such as email addresses and social media links from being discoverable by web crawlers.

I used the Angular Universal generated application to create my app. Currently, ALL my components are being rendered server-side. I couldn't find any specific clear example where someone used Angular in an elegant manner to achieve this specific goal. My intent is make my contact info and social media links components completely client-side rendered and added to the DOM at runtime to avoid bots and web crawlers from seeing it.

How do others achieve this without doing something hacky?

Comment: Why can't you just deny crawlers with robots.txt ?https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/intro

Comment: Going to look into this. Thank you!

Comment: create a directive to do that .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55407541/exclude-component-that-breaks-angular-universal/76892336#76892336

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `isPlatformBrowser` helper method for Angular and wrap all code in this helper method like below:

````
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';


export class Component {
   constructor(
     @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: string,
   ){}

   get isBrowserOnly(): boolean {
      return isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);
   }
}


<div *ngIf="isBrowserOnly">
  will be shown only in the browser
</div>


```
````

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't think of wrapping the rendering of the component in that function. I was here thinking I had to exclude the components from the module or something more complicated. Thank you!

Comment: Going to see what others reply with but you might be the chosen answer in the end. Thanks again!

Comment: would be good if Angular team provided a better way to mark the component as client-side or ssr